# Rails CKEditor - plugin doesn't work on production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, asset-pipeline

I use ckeditor gem(https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/), but it hasn't some youtube plugin.

I downloaded official youtube ckeditor plugin(http://ckeditor.com/addon/youtube) and put it into assets - it works in development mode (probable cause there isn't assets pipeline and each assets file including into page separately), but doesn't including (404 error in JS console of Chrome) in production mode, although I did assets:precompile rake task.

Probably this error cause files of plugin compiling into application.* files, but not separatyly, although it needs by ckeditor (ckeditor including all custom plugins on initialization on page).

Where I must to put this plugin (and any other assets files, that needs be separately on production instead be included in application.* files)?
And what I must to do for plugin works on production?

Comment: How many production servers do you deploy each time? Reason I'm asking is that I faced a similar issue recently and it has to do with our deployment process and rails assets precompile

Comment: @yanhan I don't use deploy tools/gems yet, just one server (unicorn+nginx).

Comment: Note down which assets you are getting a 404 for, and do a manual copy. The thing about assets:precompile is, it appends a fingerprint to the asset filenames, but some files required by ckeditor require filenames without the fingerprint appended